# Blank Email Magento 2 - Order / Password

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, email, forgot-password

At my shop I have the problem that when someone creates a **new order**, the order **confirmation (email)** is simply displayed **blank** (white page). The `email address` is also not displayed correctly.

If you `forgot Password` you get the same `blank page`.

I tried also the `standard configuration` but doesn't works.

Thanks a lot for your help
Best Regards

Comment: please provide more information. we can not help you like this

Comment: **Check Email Template Content :-**
 
    Marketing > Communications > Email Templates > New Order

Comment: Check  magento log  at var/log folder.You might be get any clue